# JSON.parse not working with double quotes in value

Tags: javascript, json

I feel like I have to be missing something simple here. I want to use JSON.parse to convert a string to a JSON object. I've been playing around with this simple example.

```
JSON.stringify({hi:'"bye"'})
//returns "{"hi":"\"bye\""}"

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({hi:'"bye"'}))
//returns Object {hi: ""bye""}

JSON.parse("{"hi":"\"bye\""}")
//returns SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

JSON.parse('{"hi":"\"bye\""}')
//Unexpected token b
```

My question is what is the difference between passing in the stringify return manually versus passing the return of stringify directly to parse? Mu ultimate goal is to be able to parse a JSON string into a JSON object where the values may contain double quotes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the third example you did not escape the first set of double-quotes. That is, `JSON.parse("{"hi":"\"bye\""}")` should be `JSON.parse("{\"hi\":\"bye\"}")`

Comment: JSON must conform to this super-simple spec: http://www.json.org/

Comment: The difference is that the your "manual" version is not a valid string literal. Have a look at it again, notice anything weird with the quotes? `"{"hi":"\"bye\""}"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes and quotation marks when you put the string representation of the object in a string using quotation mark as delimiter:

```
JSON.parse("{\"hi\":\"\\\"bye\\\"\"}")
```

When you use apostrophes as string delimiter you don't have to escape quotation marks (but you would have to escape apostrophes if you had any):

```
JSON.parse('{"hi":"\\"bye\\""}')
```

Comment: That was the issue, thanks. I knew it was something stupid on my part.